# Longitudinal data analysis in python

Tags: python, statistics, longitudinal

I have data whose structure is as below (a fictitious example):
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVsxO.png)

There are 3 predictor variables and 1 response variable.
We have data of 5 students, and each student have 3 observations for time 1,2,3. Thus total number of observations is 15.

But I don't have an idea how to analyze the effect of X1, X2, X3 on Y in this kind of longitudinal data.(I will use python)

Can anyone give me some idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have longitudinal data and a continuous response you have a few different options:

1. Ignore the grouping structure. I would not recommend doing this, since you may be ignoring information.
2. Model your groups separately. This is usually not a good idea, and most certainly not in the case where the groups have low sample size.
3. Treat your grouping variable as a categorical predictor. This is again may not be ideal when the number of groups are high, even with recent boosting packages that handle categorical predictors with high cardinality well (e.g. [CatBoost](https://github.com/catboost/catboost)).
4. Use a mixed effects model.

If you want to proceed with bullet 4, I recommend taking a look at the [Gaussian Process Boosting or GPBoost package](https://github.com/fabsig/GPBoost) first. However, there are other Python packages to consider: [MERF](https://github.com/manifoldai/merf) and LMER in [Statsmodels](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels).